# Icicle: After load icicles the ido mode is gone?

Tags: ido, find-file, ido-find-file, icicles

windows 10, emacs 26.1, icicles

Before **Icicles** when I type `C-x C-f` is show list of folders/files in **ido** mode. And it's very comfortable for me.

But after I install **Icicles** and turn on `icy-mode` the **ido** mode is gone (e.g. when I type `C-x C-f`). Is it normal? Now is show **Icicles** candidates to complete. OK, but I want to work with **ido** mode.
Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not really surprised because icy-mode and ido-mode solve the same problem. No wonder there's a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at the [Icicles documentation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles). Section [Icicles - Ido and IswitchB](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Ido_and_IswitchB) covers this.

It tells you, for example, *"You cannot use Icicles and Ido together, however – they use the minibuffer in incompatible ways."*

However, you *can* use [Icicles and **Icomplete**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Icompletion) together. Icomplete shows you completion candidates in the minibuffer (and lets you choose them) in a way similar to Ido.

[Icicles - Ido and IswitchB](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Ido_and_IswitchB) also tells you how you can get more Ido-like behavior while using Icicles. There are different parts of Ido behavior that you can obtain, with respect to: incremental completion, non-expansion of minibuffer input, matching, cycling and sorting, current candidate, editing input, display of completions, auto-choice of single candidate, and more.

That page also tells you that to get Ido-like behavior for files (your `C-x C-f` example) you just need to customize option [icicle-files-ido-like-flag](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Customization_and_General_Tips#icicle-files-ido-like-flag).